# How to know if a URL is decoded/encoded?

Tags: javascript, urlencode, urldecode

I am using Javascript method `decodeURIComponent` to decode an encoded URL. Now I am having an issue, that sometimes the URL is get encoded twice during redirection between servers, sometimes it is encoded only once.

I want to check that if the URL is still encoded after calling the method `decodeURIComponent`. How can I do that? Any pointer would be very helpful to me.

### Update - 1

If I recursively call a method and check that if the given URL still contains "%", if it contains "%" then decode it and call the method again; and if not return it to the caller, will that work?

### Update - 2

For my case I have:

```
callBackUrl=http%253A%252F%252Fadbc.com%252FPOSM%252Fapp%252Fpages%252Fadf.task-flow%253Fadf.tfDoc%253D%25252FWEB-INF%25252Ftask-flows%25252Fcatalog-edit-task-flow.xml%2526adf.tfId%253Dcatalog%2526_adf.ctrl-state%253Db9akorh22_9%2526articleReference%253D10C00135%2526previousView%253Dcatalog-home%2526fromUCM%253Dtrue%2526articleType%253Dposm%2526developer%253Dcentral
```

Now I am taking the value of the callBackUrl in my js method, then decoding it and firing `window.open()` with that decoded URL. the parameters are same and it has:

- adf.tfDoc
- adf.tfId
- articleReference
- previousView
- fromUCM
- articleType
- developer

Parameters into it. So I know there is no query string like `value="%.."`.

### Update - 3

I have written the following method:

```
var decodeURLRecursively = function(url) {
    if(url.indexOf('%') != -1) {
        return decodeURLRecursively(decodeURIComponent(url));
    }

    return url;
}
```

Comment: Seems like an issue to be fixed on the server rather than patching it on the front end.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, you can encode a string twice. And this may look either as twice encoded string or as an attempt to send an encoded string.

Comment: @elclanrs, maybe it is an issue in the server, but is there any way to check my requirement?

Comment: @mishik I have updated my question, could you please take a look?

Comment: @TapasBose what if you want to pass `value=%` to the server?

Comment: @mishik could you please take a look at my second update?

Comment: Could a workaround solution be to add an additional query param called encoded and set to true if it's encoded and false if it's not. Then if the url is encoded, don't encode again. Otherwise, you could add a number, encoded being the key, the value being the number of times it's been encoded, then you can decode the required number of times.

Comment: @MichaelMartinez, don't think so. Otherwise, it won't be a generic solution. Since this sanitization is done on the callee side, who is unaware of the type of caller.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Repeatedly decoding until you find no `%` signs will work over 99% of the time. It'll work even better if you repeatedly call so long as a match for `/%[0-9a-f]{2}/i` can be found.

However, if I were (for some bizarre reason) to name a file `100%achieved`, that would cause a problem because `%ac` would be decoded to `¬`, causing the decode to fail. Unfortunately there's no way to detect this case.

Ideally you should know if something is encoded more than once, and optimally you shouldn't let it happen in the first place.

Comment: By repeatedly decoding you mean a recursive call?

Comment: No, I mean a `do..while` loop.

Comment: I will give a try to the `do..while`, however I have written a recursion in my Update - 3. Please take a look.

Comment: I don't like recursive functions in general, because it is extremely easy to get stuck in an infinite loop and blow up the call stack. On the other hand, an infinite `do..while` loop will cause the browser to hang/crash, but at least it won't consume all the available memory before doing so.

Comment: What I do is simply to search for **space ( )**,**line-breaks (\n)**, **carriage-return (\r)** and **tag (\t)** characters.
In my case I want to execute a JavaScript via the browsers address bar.
`javascript:alert('test string')`
so it is sufficient for me.

Answer (score 57):

There is a simple way to konw if a URL string is encoded.

Take the initial string and compare it with the result of decoding it. If the result is the same, the string is not encoded; if the result is different then it is encoded.

I had this issue with my urls and I used this functions:

```
function isEncoded(uri) {
  uri = uri || '';

  return uri !== decodeURIComponent(uri);
}
```

So now I can use `isEncoded` as the discriminant in a while loop (or with recursion) to know if I need to keep calling `decodeURIComponent` on the string:

```
function fullyDecodeURI(uri){

  while (isEncoded(uri)){
    uri = decodeURIComponent(uri);
  }

  return uri;
}
```

This solved the problem for me of decoding urls encoded multiple times. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx, helped me alot :)

Comment: Still doesn't work if your decoded url has a %20 in the filename or something.

Comment: 1 line version:
`const isEncoded = uri => uri !== decodeURIComponent(uri || '')`

Comment: Nice function! As a string could contain a "normal" percent sign, decodeURIComponent will trigger and error which you can catch. Which could mean the string is unencoded, so that would be a nice addition to this

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkEncodeURI(str) {
 return /\%/i.test(str)
}
```

Test :

```
let url1 = "https://quora.com/unanswered/I’m-looking-for-a-Freaks-And-Friends-Fox-Glitter-Face-Hinge-Wallet-for-a-Christmas-gift-I’ve-searched-for-hours-online-but-no-one-seemed-to-have-it-does-anyone-know-where-I-can-find-one"
let url2 = 'https://www.quora.com/unanswered/I%E2%80%99m-looking-for-a-Freaks-And-Friends-Fox-Glitter-Face-Hinge-Wallet-for-a-Christmas-gift-I%E2%80%99ve-searched-for-hours-online-but-no-one-seemed-to-have-it-does-anyone-know-where-I-can-find-one'
let a = checkEncodeURI(url1)
console.log(a)
let b = checkEncodeURI(url2)
console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can keep decode until the string did not change:

```
str = "xxxxxxx"
dec_str = decode(str)
while(dec_str != str)
     str = dec_str;
     dec_str = decode(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is really simple and fast and trusted way to know if a URL string is encoded or Not.

For Example:
decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent("SWQgPSA0NjI%3D"))) <> "SWQgPSA0NjI="  ---->  Not equal to orginal value      then Already encoded

just this code:

```
  var encValue = encodeURIComponent(Value);
    try {
         if (decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(encValue)) === Value) {
          //not encodec yet...so return encoded of val
          return encValue;
         }
       } catch (err) {
           //not encodec yet...so return encoded of val
           return encValue;
       }

 return Value  //same value returned
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this helpful when I was experiencing a similar issue.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

```js
function containsEncodedComponents(x) {
  // ie ?,=,&,/ etc
  return (decodeURI(x) !== decodeURIComponent(x));
}

console.log(containsEncodedComponents('%3Fx%3Dtest')); // ?x=test
// Expected output: true

console.log(containsEncodedComponents('%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8B')); // шеллы
// Expected output: false
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).