# Javascript, URL encoded multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, query-string, urlencode

For a ReactJs application I'm using this code:

```
let service  = new URL(`/${accessRoute}`, this.authOriginService);
service.searchParams.set('origin', origin);
service.searchParams.set('id', id);

const finalUrl  = new URL(mainService);
finalUrl.searchParams.set('id', id);
finalUrl.searchParams.set('service', service);
```

The 'origin' parameter is an URL that I retrieve as a queryString parameter.

This works fine, but I have a problem for a specific scenario.

I noticed that, only in this case, the origin URL is already encoded, and from what I understand, when I generate the final URL, it seems to be encoded twice.

Is this a reasonable observation? If so, how can I avoid encoding this URL multiple times?

Comment: "The 'origin' parameter is an URL that I retrieve as a queryString parameter." - How exactly do you read this parameter from the query string? Perhaps you are doing it in an incorrect way (e.g. regex, simple string split,...) that doesn't decode it. Of course you could just do `decodeURIComponent(origin)` but it's better to fix the root cause of this issue, if possible.

Comment: You can try adding a function to check whether the URL is encoded already
Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38265168) for example

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.